# An inequality based on conditional independence of resampling

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, sampling, bootstrap-sampling

Suppose we have  i.i.d. samples $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ and $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_{K_n}$ comes from resampling from $X$ with replacement, $K_n\leq n$. Can we say that $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_{K_n}$ are i.i.d conditional on $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$, and use the Dvoretzky-Kiefer-Wolfowitz inequality to get:
$$P\left(\left|\frac{1}{K_n} \sum_{i=1}^{K_n} 1(Y_i \leq 0 )-\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1(X_i \leq 0 )\right|\geq \sqrt{\frac{log(2n)}{2K_n}}\right)\leq \frac{1}{n}
$$

Comment: You seem to have two binomial distributions

Comment: My point is that conditional on $X_1,...,X_n$, we can define a new random variable $Z$ which takes value of $X_i,i=1,..,n$ with probability $1/n$,. Denote the distribution function and empirical distribution function of $Z$ are $F$ and $\hat{F}$, then the two terms in  the absolute value symbol | · | are $\hat{F_{K_n}}(0)-F(0)$. I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: My point is that the setup to your question is equivalent to $A \sim Bin(n,p)$ for $p=\mathbb P(X_1\le0)$ and conditioned on $A$ then $B \sim Bin(K_n, \frac An)$ with your question being about $\left|\frac{B}{K_n} - \frac{A}{n}\right|$.  My guess is that this is more likely to be higher when $p=\frac12$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think maybe both our ideas are available because  E$(\frac{B}{K_n})=\frac{A}{n},$ and hence we can use something like Markov or Chernoff inequality to give a similar bound ?

Comment: Also, independence of $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ seems unnecessary.

Comment: In that case you may be saying that $P\left(\left|\frac{Z}{k} -q\right|\geq \sqrt{\frac{\log(2n)}{2k}}\right)\leq \frac{1}{n}$ for $Z \sim Bin(k,q)$.

Comment: I think Chebyshev's inequality could give you $P\left(\left|\frac{Z}{k} -q\right|\geq \sqrt{\frac{nq(1-q)}{k}  }\right)\leq \frac{1}{n}$ which is not tight enough for large $n$ so you need something better